# How to make a JAX-RS Apache/Jetty server allow external machines to connect?

Tags: java, jetty, server, jax-rs, cxf

Here is the code for my server startup:

```
import org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Server;
import org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean;
import org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.lifecycle.SingletonResourceProvider;

public class MyServer{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JAXRSServerFactoryBean sf = new JAXRSServerFactoryBean();
        sf.setResourceClasses(RequestHandler.class);
        sf.setResourceProvider(RequestHandler.class,
            new SingletonResourceProvider(new RequestHandler()));
        sf.setAddress("http://localhost:9999/scorecard/");

        Server server = sf.create(); 
    }
}
```

Everything works when I do http://localhost:9999/scorecard/ on the server machine.

How can I make it so that when I go to http://MyIPAddress:9999/scorecard/ in a browser on a different computer on my LAN, it connects properly?

Comment: can you ping the computer? ports closed?

Comment: I was able to ping the IP for the server. How can I see if the port is closed?

Comment: Interesting question... Depends on the OS, if it's Windows(r) I have no clue, for Linux you have IP tables... But can you so the log of Jetty? Or go to http://MyIPAddress:9999/ (without the `scorecard`), jetty should tell the exact url (if running).

Comment: fixed it. changed         sf.setAddress("http://localhost:9999/scorecard/"); to         sf.setAddress("http://MyIP:9999/scorecard/");